# How to share on Instagram from Web App in a user friendly way?

Tags: instagram, user-experience

From iOS app it is possible to share content to Instagram, is it any trick for Web apps?

My only idea, prepare image for user to download image from the website to the disk, then notice him in an alert, he can open Instagram and add the image there.

Do you know any more ease solution?

---

If I good understand Instagram Graph API is only for Business accounts, so an app can not post in behalf of a user.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api